# Linux CentOS 7 printer installation, what is the hpps program?

Tags: linux, centos, printing, printer, centos-7

I just installed Linux CentOS 7 on my laptop. I tried to install my local printer, but it does not work.

At the end of the configuration process, the system shows a window stating:

> Printer 'tmdtpr1_11' requires the '/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpps' program
>   but it is not currently installed.  Please install it before using
>   this printer.

I looked for the program **hpps** but I cannot find it, it does not seem to exist.
How could I solve this? What could I do?

Answer (score 5):

#### What is the hpps program?

HPPS is the HPLIP PostScript Finishing Filter.

---

#### How do I install it?

Full installation instructions can be found at [Manual Build and Install Instructions for CentOS](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/manual/distros/centos.html)

---

#### HP Linux imaging and printing

> **Technical Overview**
>
> The Hewlett-Packard Linux Imaging and Printing project (HPLIP) provides a unified solution to print, scan, fax and configure HP single and multi-function devices which works with many Linux distributions. The goal of this project is to provide "radically simple" printing, faxing, scanning, and device management to consumer and small business desktop Linux users. This project is based on open source software and uses GPL compatible licenses.

...

> HPLIP PostScript Finishing Filter (hpps) implements special functionalities like, Job storage (Secure Printing), Job Accounting and Born On Date (BOD) features on specific capable printers.

Source [HP Linux imaging and printing](http://hplipopensource.com/node/128)

Answer (score 4):

On EL7 (CentOS, RHEL, etc.), install the “hplip” package using `yum install hplip`.  It should be in the base repo. I don't have a Ubuntu/Debian or Fedora box around, but it's likely available for those too.

Answer (score 3):

Login as super user.

```
# yum install hplip

# system-config-printer
```

This should work.

Else you can try `# yum install cups`

and follow system config.

Answer (score 2):

Try out 'yum install cups'.  I have to use this application often since my family periodically updates the latest version of Linux Mint and any printer configuration files are erased.  After you have 'cups' fully installed, go into a browser and put 'localhost:631' into the URL bar.  This is where you can configure your printers from on most *nix machines.

Hope this helps!